# Without my metal, I'm big in Japan

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I'm a rag with power
>
> A part of me bears fruit
>
> Another part is lighter than a fly
>
> I can come in very large groups,
>
> We can be more than exponential in size

**What am I?**

* Title is also a hint

Hint (extra line)

> I'm a Japanese noodle with a g

Hint (title)

> Periodic table

Hint (last two lines)

> The size of the group is more than an exponential function of something

Hint (extra line)

> I'm a sheep of the nagging type

Comment: 555 Rep :P sorry to ruin it but +1

Comment: The title made me think SUNSHINE - N and Ne = SUSHI but that doesn’t fit and neon nor nitrogen are metals

Comment: I like the puzzle. Too many hints in a too short period though. Don’t spoil your own puzzles by being impatient! Give it 48+ hrs or so.

Comment: Japanese noodle with AG (silver), but [silver needle noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_needle_noodles) is chinese.

Comment: Some short-named Japanese noodles are ramen/lamen, soba and udon. Ramen with G can be gramen, which has "gram" ("lighter than a fly"). But that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you an

> anagram?

---

Without my metal, I'm big in Japan

> anagram - Ra (radium) = “manga”

I'm a rag with power

> “mana rag”

A part of me bears fruit

> Ana is the mother of the Virgin Mary. If this interpretation is correct, this is the same sense of “fruit” used in the prayer Ave Maria (“fruit of thy womb”). Or it could be “argan” (a little-known fruit-bearing tree of the Sahara), or even less likely just “ag” (short for agriculture).

Another part is lighter than a fly

> “gram”

I can come in very large groups

> A word can have many anagrams

We can be more than exponential in size

> The number of possible anagrams increases <s>exponentially</s> factorially (thanks **ffao**) with number of letters in a word

I'm a Japanese noodle with a g

> ?? “raman” instead of “ramen”?

I'm a sheep of the nagging type

> “a nag ram”

Comment: This has to be right. For the exponential line: it actually grows as a factorial, which grows faster than exponentials.

Comment: @ffao, you're right, thanks. I'll add this information, I just want to give "bears fruit" and "Japenese noodle" some more thought first.

Comment: I found a more reasonable explanation for "a part of me bears fruit", but "I'm a Japanese noodle with a g" still needs to be properly explained.

Comment: for 'a part of me bears fruit' there's a simpler solution

Comment: The raman is right, raman + a + g == anagram

Comment: Flies tend to weight less then a gram though. There's obviously no exact data, but the weight of a housefly is estimated around 12 mg...

Answer (score 4):

This might be stretching it but after trying to figure this out for about an hour, I think I just need confirmation that the answer is or is not

> Birch

Without my metal, I'm big in Japan

> According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch#Taxonomy), there are 11 different species of birch that are native to Japan. However, **silver** birch is **not** native to Japan. Silver is a metal.

I'm a rag with power

> Birch is one species of tree that is used for wood pulp, which is made into newspaper. The term 'rag' can be used to describe a [newspaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rag), and 'power' can either be talking about the process that converts birch to pulp, or the fact that newspapers can be powerful in terms of communications or propaganda.

A part of me bears fruit

> Some (if not all) birch trees produce fruit called [samara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch#Flower_and_fruit).

Another part is lighter than a fly

> Can be talking about multiple things including samara, leaves, or the weight of a single piece of newspaper.

I can come in very large groups,

> A forest of birch trees.

We can be more than exponential in size

> From a little seed a mighty birch tree can grow.

Comment: Very nice! Everything seems to fit very well except the last one. I wouldn't say a tree is exponentially larger than a seed (exponent is a function of something). It's not at all what I meant, but it's really impressive. well done

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Water?

Without my metal, I'm big in Japan:

> Even if I cannot come up with something about "Without my metal", I thought this is something related to tsunami in Japan.

I'm a rag with power

> Sea or ocean.

A part of me bears fruit

> With CO2, it's the main fuel for plants.

Another part is lighter than a fly

> Vapour or clouds

I can come in very large groups,

> This line tells about rain.

We can be more than exponential in size

> First thing I thought was the shape of a wave , which does look like (not exactly, but it does) an exponential function graph. Also related with the tsunami.